# SQLiteCursors aren't being notified, aidl files don't exist

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentresolver, aidl

(EDITED TWICE)

My sqlite cursors are not being notified of changes, even though I set the notification when I create them and notify them when the db is accessed.  I tried something like this to test the methods:

```
weatherCursor.getCount(); // returns 1
deleteAllRecords();
Uri uri = weatherCursor.getNotificationUri();
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
weatherCursor.getCount(); // still returns 1
weatherCursor.close();
weatherCursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
weatherCursor.getCount(); //finally returns 0
```

When I tried to dig into the source for `ContentResolver.notifyChange`, I found that it tries to use a class called `IContentObserver`, but the import cannot be resolved.  It does this in a try block, and the catch block is empty, so it silently fails.

Similarly, `AbstractCursor.setNotificationUri` calls `ContentResolver.registerContentObserver`, which tries to use a class called `IContentService`, also within a try block with an empty catch.  Unlike above, I didn't even see an import statement for `IContentService`.

A commenter (@Lawrence Choy) explained that "`IContentObserver` is actually an auto-generated file which is defined in `IContentObserver.aidl`."  I serached my entire system for "IContentObserver.aidl", and the only hit was the file Android Studio uses to store recent searches, so I don't have this file on my computer.  I'm not sure where the file is supposed to be, but I tried deleting and reinstalling the build tools and the API through the SDK manager, and I still don't have it anywhere.

[ANOTHER EDIT]
The above snippet (run in the evaluator) was intended to boil all the following code down to the relevent parts, but here is a more complete set of code.  First is the code for `deleteAllRecords()`, which is the method in one of my test units that is failing. It successfully deletes all records but fails to update the cursors, which I had taken for granted.

```
public void deleteAllRecords() {

    Cursor weatherCursor = queryWholeTable(mContext, WeatherEntry.CONTENT_URI);
    Cursor locationCursor = queryWholeTable(mContext, LocationEntry.CONTENT_URI);

    int initialWeatherCount = weatherCursor.getCount();
    int initialLocationCount = locationCursor.getCount();

    int deletedWeatherCount = mContext.getContentResolver().delete(
            WeatherEntry.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            null
    );
    int finalWeatherCount = weatherCursor.getCount();
    int deletedLocationCount = mContext.getContentResolver().delete(
            LocationEntry.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            null
    );
    int finalLocationCount = locationCursor.getCount();

    assertEquals(initialWeatherCount, deletedWeatherCount);
//ASSERT BELOW FAILS!
    assertEquals(0, finalWeatherCount);
    weatherCursor.close();

    assertEquals(initialLocationCount, deletedLocationCount);
//ASSERT BELOW FAILS!
    assertEquals(0, finalLocationCount);
    locationCursor.close();

    //Added when above tests failed to see if records were actually deleted.

    weatherCursor = queryWholeTable(mContext, WeatherEntry.CONTENT_URI);
    locationCursor = queryWholeTable(mContext, LocationEntry.CONTENT_URI);

    int weatherVeryFinal = weatherCursor.getCount();
    int locationVeryFinal = locationCursor.getCount();

    assertEquals(0, weatherVeryFinal);
    assertEquals(0, locationVeryFinal);

    locationCursor.close();
    weatherCursor.close();

}
```

Here is `.queryWholeTable`:

```
public static Cursor queryWholeTable(Context context, Uri uri){
    return context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
}
```

And here are the `.delete` and `.query` methods of `WeatherProvider`:

```
@Override
public int delete(Uri targetUri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    final int match = sUriMatcher.match(targetUri);
    final String table;
    final Uri notificationUri;
    switch (match) {
        case WEATHER:
            table = WeatherEntry.TABLE_NAME;
            notificationUri = WeatherEntry.CONTENT_URI;
            break;
        case LOCATION:
            table = LocationEntry.TABLE_NAME;
            notificationUri = LocationEntry.CONTENT_URI;
            break;
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown delete uri: " + targetUri.toString());
    }
    int affected = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase().delete(table, selection, selectionArgs);
    if (selection == null || affected > 0) {
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(notificationUri, null);
    }
    return affected;
}

public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
                    String sortOrder) {
    // Here's the switch statement that, given a URI, will determine what kind of request it is,
    // and query the database accordingly.
    Cursor retCursor;
    switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        // "weather/*/*"
        case WEATHER_WITH_LOCATION_AND_DATE: {
            retCursor = getWeatherByLocationSetting(uri, projection, sortOrder, true);
            break;
        }
        // "weather/*"
        case WEATHER_WITH_LOCATION: {
            retCursor = getWeatherByLocationSetting(uri, projection, sortOrder, false);
            break;
        }
        // "weather"
        case WEATHER: {
            retCursor = mOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase().query(
                    WeatherEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                    projection,
                    selection,
                    selectionArgs,
                    null,
                    null,
                    sortOrder
            );
            break;
        }
        // "location/*"
        case LOCATION_ID: {
            retCursor = mOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase().query(
                    LocationEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                    projection,
                    LocationEntry._ID + " = " + ContentUris.parseId(uri),
                    selectionArgs,
                    null,
                    null,
                    sortOrder
            );
            break;
        }
        // "location"
        case LOCATION: {
            retCursor = mOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase().query(
                    LocationEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                    projection,
                    selection,
                    selectionArgs,
                    null,
                    null,
                    sortOrder
            );
            break;
        }

        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri: " + uri);
    }
    retCursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return retCursor;
}
```

As you can see, `.setNotificationUri` is always called when cursors are created, and `.notifyChange` is always called when anything is deleted.

Comment: Are you trying to override `ContentResolver` or simply cannot build the project with normal usage?

Comment: I'm not trying to override ContentResolver, and actually the project does build and run, but my cursors are not being notified of changes, and when I tried to look through the source for `ContentResolver.notifyChange()`, I found that it called IContentObserver.notifyChange` and was stumped.  This leaves me unsure whether my code is causing the problem, or the missing file.

Comment: I suspect this is not the cause of your problem. `IContentObserver` is actually a auto-generated file which is defined in `IContentObserver.aidl`. This file is generated when you build from Android source files, which may not exists in the source from which you downloaded in SDK Manager. When you run the application, the device eventually will have this file available.

Comment: the sources bundled with sdk are just for reference, they are never built. The call is done in frameworks.jar so the chances of framework having bug are minuscule. Can you post the code where you are registering for callback.

Comment: What are the contents of `deleteAllRecords()`?

Comment: Could you mark code lines where assertions fail?

Comment: Marked them each with comment `//ASSERT BELOW FAILS!`.  If I comment out those two assertions, all tests pass.

Answer (score 1):

AIDL is not the reason. The reason is how you load your data - do you access it directly from SQLiteDatabase, or do you use Loader to query it?

Cursor is just one of those "lazy-loading" patterns, it is unaware of what's happening to underlying data. To watch for content changes, you need an observer - e.g., Loader.

1) If you do not use loader/contentprovider, your cursors are not being notified and you have to handle cursor invalidation yourself.

2) If you use Loader, - I guess it is a CursorLoader, which loads data from some Uri. In this case it is common to have a ContentProvider, which facades SQLite CRUD operations and notifies all the subscribers (e.g., existing Loaders) about content change.

It seems like you either stick with 1), or yout implementation of 2) is wrong.

I suggest you read further about ContentProvider, Loader and see some examples. You might checkout one of the apps from [my repo](https://github.com/ousenko), e.g. [this one](https://github.com/ousenko/Air) (notice usage of CursorLoader, implementation of LoaderManager, implementation of ContentProvider), and watch them in action in your IDE.

Comment: I am trying to use a ContentProvider, and I know my implementation is wrong.

Comment: I looked at loaders, and it yes they update automatically, but isn't that what `.notifyChange` and `.setNotificationUri` are supposed to do for regular cursors?  It looks like the fundamental advantage of loaders is that they work asynchronously, which is good to know but doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: `.setNotificationUri` tells Cursor to monitor ContentProvider Uri for changes. If your ContentProvider implementation is wrong - then your Cursor might not get notified. If you insert data directly into SQLite db, and do not use ContentResolver for this purpose - your Cursor will not be updated.
Advantages of Loader: asynchronous, memory-leak-proof, manages cursor for you, monitors for data chages

Comment: Anyway, hard to tell anything more specific without more code details

Comment: Okay, so I can (probably) use `CursorLoader` to sidestep this problem entirely, but I'd like to find out why this isn't working.  Basically I'm asking why `.setNotifactionUri` and `.notifyChange` aren't working, and you're both just telling me to start from the top with a different implementation.  Google didn't provide those methods just to trick me; there must be a way to use them properly that I am missing.

Comment: Also, I put all the code I thought might be relevent up there.  If you think something *specific* is missing, let me know.  In particular, you can see that `.query` always calls `.setNotificationUri` and `.delete` always calls `.notifyChange`.  And from the original snippet I posted, you can see that uri mismatch is not the problem, because it doesn't work even when I notify the uri returned by `.getNotificationUri`.

Comment: But thank you both for telling me about CursorLoader, really.  I will use it in the future, but this is just a learning exercise for me and I want to learn how cursors are used properly.

Comment: Haha, I just noticed I said "you both" to a single person.